Am I right in calculate this surface intagral?
The following is the question is from Electrodynamics 4th edition, page 26:
Calculate the surface integral of $$v = 2x z \hat{x}  + (x+2)  \hat{y} + y(z^2−3)
 \hat{z}$$ over five sides (excluding the bottom) of the cubical box (side 2) in Fig. 1.23.
Let “upward and outward” be the positive direction, as indicated by the arrows.

When x = 2
$$ v = 4 z  \hat{x} + 4 \hat{y} + y (z^2 - 3) \hat{z} $$
$$v_y  = (z^2 - 3) \hat{z} , v_z = 4 \hat{x} + 2 z y \hat{z} $$
$$v_y \times v_z = 4 (z^2 -3) \hat{y} $$
$$4 \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2} \mid z^2 - 3 \mid dz dy$$
However, the book said this.
$$4 \int_{0}^{2} dy \int_{0}^{2} zdz$$

What you are suppose to calculate is the integral of $v\cdot \hat n$. In this case, at $x=2$, the normal to the surface is along $\hat x$. So $$v\cdot \hat n=v\cdot \hat x=2xz=4z$$and the integral should be $$4\int_0^2 dy\int_0^2zdz$$
I've used $\hat x\cdot \hat x=\hat y\cdot \hat y=\hat z\cdot \hat z=1$ and $\hat x\cdot \hat y=\hat y\cdot \hat z=\hat z\cdot \hat x=0$

Why do you think it's dot product instead of cross product?
https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section16.07.html suggest it's usually cross product with parameterized?
Let  Σ
be a surface in  $R^3$
parametrized by  x=x(u,v),y=y(u,v),z=z(u,v), for (u,v)
in some region  R
in  $R^2$

The flux is a scalar quantity. If you write the surface element as a cross product of vectors along the surface you get a unit vector normal to the surface multiplied by the surface element $\vec r_u\times\vec r_v=\hat n dS$. Now you need to use the scalar product to multiply this with your function. You could have used $(d\vec y\times d\vec z)\cdot v(x,y,z)=v_x(x,y,z)dxdy$ in your integral

In my opinion, $\mbox{$\Large\frac{\vec{r_u} \times \vec{r_v}} {\mid \mid \vec{r_u} \times \vec{r_v} \mid \mid}  =  \hat{n} $}$. the lenght of normal vector $\hat{n}$ shouild be  1

Correct. And $||\vec r_u\times\vec r_v||=dS$. In this particular case, $\vec r_u=dy\hat y$, $\vec r_v=dz\hat z$, so $\vec r_u\times\vec r_v=dy dz\hat x$

How  do you know $\vec{r_u} = dy \hat{y}$, $\vec{r_v} = dz \hat{z}$.
Isn't that supposed to be $$r_u  = (z^2 - 3) \hat{z} , r_v = 4 \hat{x} + 2 z y \hat{z} $$?

No. I think you are confused about those vectors. They are supposed to be along the surface. The surface is not dependent on the function $v$. You would have the same expression for those even if you don't know $v$. For example, at a corner the $v$ and derivative are the same, but the surface normals are in different directions.
